# Dell docking station only works when power supply unplugged

Tags: power-supply, docking-station, dell-precision

I recently was forced to get a new Dell M6500 chassis and hard-drive for work to replace my old identical model laptop. I have a Dell docking station connected to some peripherals and a second monitor, all of which were/are working fine. However, my new laptop will only dock if the power supply in the back is **unplugged**. When the laptop is on battery and docked, it happily accepts the usb keyboard and mouse and recognizes the second monitor, but the instant I plug the in the dock power supply, the monitor shuts off and the peripherals stop working.

This is the same make/model, docking station, and power supply as my old laptop, the only difference being the new SSD instead of HD. Additionally, I've tried on several other docks/power-supplies I know to be working. I've updated all my drivers that I could, and tried to clean the docking pins off on the laptop. The only thing I can think of is that the power supply is different, however I don't know why this would be the case.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check the power supply weather it is the right matching power supply with the exact frequency and power rating. Using the correct power supply will fix the problem

Comment: @vembutech, thanks for the answer. The laptop is the same model as my old laptop, with the only difference being the HDD was swapped out with a SSD. The power supply should therefore work the same I would think. I have tried multiple power supplies as well.